# Open a tab in Mozilla Add On SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Mozilla Add on. I am trying to open a tab.

According to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html  it is done using

```
console.log("before tab");
var tabs = require("tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.example.com");
```

But it is not working on my case.

I am doing that in the content script. 
I have a page called popup.html and a content called popup_script.js.

The code is reached because the message is logged.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content scripts don't have access to "advanced" APIs, they can merely communicate with the extension. So your content script should [send a message to the extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/using-port.html) and the extension should open the tab then. Like this:

```
self.port.emit("openTab", "http://www.example.com");
```

And in `main.js`:

```
panel.port.on("openTab", function(url)
{
  var tabs = require("tabs");
  tabs.open(url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this tomorrow. 
I want to open a tab to login to facebook and come back. Is that possible?

Comment: You can detect when the tab is closed (`tab.on("close", function() {...})`) if that's what you mean...